# "HELP" Command in REPLIT in PYTHON

Tags: python, linux

I don't know why whenever I use replit in terminal of manjaro linux I got stuck on one thing.
Whenever I try help command in replit. yeah it gives me output but it get stuck by giving message END.

And I don't know how to quit it so I just terminate the process or cut the terminal.

So have to know if there is any way I can escape from python rather exiting from Terminal?

I was trying HELP command and was thinking to get output though I got but wasn't able to go back.

Comment: Did you try `q`?

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you're doing, but this doesn't seem to be about programming, so it's off-topic here. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] for an introduction to SO.

Comment: @tadman nope I didn't..

Comment: actually I came back to windows. so here everything seems fine for now